# Gwt Css and uibinder no-obfuscation not working

Tags: css, gwt, obfuscation

I have a Gwt widget library with configuration property:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="stable-notype"/>
```

which is expected to leave original css names, then a css file (example)

```
.invader {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
}

.invader .button {
    background-image: url('merged.png');
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-position: 0px 64px;
    background-color: #BA6622;
}
```

after that, a generated css resource

```
interface WidgetStyle extends CssResource {
  String button();
  String invader();
}
```

And when I call ensureInjected() on WidgetStyle instance (and/or) use styles programatically/in ui:binder with e.g.

```
<ui:style src="WidgetStyle.css" field="style" />
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.invader}" ui:field="panel" />
```

Then, in result html file in browser instead of one injected css styles i got four defined selectors:

```
.org-invader-widget-client-WidgetStyle-invader;
.org-invader-widget-client-WidgetStyle-invader .org-invader-widget-client-WidgetStyle-button;
.org-invader-widget-client-MyWidget_UIImpl_GenCss_style-invader;
.org-invader-widget-client-MyWidget_UIImpl_GenCss_style-invader .org-invader-widget-client-MyWidget_UIImpl_GenCss_style-button;
```

Those pairs duplicate the styles above just with different names. I see that the second pair come as "MyWidget owned" styles, but how can I force all application to use only those css classes i defined in a .css file without any obfuscation?

Futhermore, the second pair of css-classess fails to apply properly. Only the first is applied, second is not matched.

What I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found that accessing css with

```
<ui:style ... />
```

injects styles and css classes might get extra prefix, proper way for me was to access styles by a ClientBundle with

```
<ui:with ... >
```

Obfuscation overriding does not work 'by default' in SuperDevMode in *.gwt.xml and, if I am right, it has to be configured with DevMode run parameter.

Comment: As far as I know, this cannot be done with a run parameter for gwt 2.7+. There is an info in the recompile.java line 510 (https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.8.0-rc2/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/Recompiler.java) which says, obfuscating in superdev is necessary.